# Keeping state of DataFrame between cython calls

Tags: c++, pandas, cython

I have C++ code that calls DLL which contains cythonized python functions. The python functions work with DataFrame (create it and then do lookups / stuff on it). I would like to do the DataFrame creation only once, which means I need to keep its state after the python function exits.

I haven't found a way how to return the DataFrame pointer from cython factory to C++ and send it from C++ to the other cython functions later. I want to avoid singleton-like solutions in cython. Please advise.

Edit1:
foo.pyx:

```
cdef public string Foo( const string& csvpath ) except *:
    cdef string c_csvpath = csvpath
    #...
```

foo.h:

```
__PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(std::string) Foo(std::string const &);
```

Comment: Could you show (a simplified version of) how you're calling your dll. Is is using [one of `public` or `api`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c)? It think it's probably pretty easy to save the `DataFrame` but it's a bit difficult to guess what you've done right now,.

Comment: I am doing the "public" call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want to keep the `string` return type (if not then you can just return a Python object, which you may find easier). If this is the case then you need to use one of the function arguments to store data. Any mutable Python object could be used in principle but I'm going to demonstrate with a dictionary since I think that makes most sense:

```
cdef public string Foo( const string& csvpath, dict saved_data ) except *:
    cdef string c_csvpath = csvpath

    # get the DataFrame if possible, otherwise generate it
    try:
        df = saved_data['dataframe']
    except KeyError:
        df = 3.3 # somehow generate your dataframe


    # at the end make sure everything's updated
    saved_data['dataframe'] = df
    return csvpath
```

The C signature becomes:

```
__PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(std::string) Foo(std::string const &, PyObject *);
```

In your C++ code you then need to create and save a dictionary:

```
PyObject* data = PyDict_New();
// good code would check for null here

string out = Foo(string("Hi"),data);

// your data dictionary should now have "dataframe" in it

// a second call, reusing the data frame
string out2 = Foo(string("Hi"),data);

// once you're sure you've done with the data frame
Py_DECREF(data); // frees it, unless Python also has a copy
```

Comment: Much appreciated.